# Visual Basic System Text Encoding GetBytes without EOF / EOL

Tags: vb.net, encoding

I try to read a string, to hash it, but when I use (e.g. with string "0")

```
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("0")
```

to generate the Bytes to hash I always get the EOF / EOL as the last byte.

Is there an easy way to not get the EOL / EOF within the byte array, or do I have to cut the last byte of the byte array, to get rid of this?

Comment: Pass a `Char` array to `GetBytes` instead of a `String`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That doesn't do anything different from what the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

[Encoding.Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=netframework-4.7) is

> An encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order.

This means that there are (at least) two bytes per character. It is easy to demonstrate what happens when you get the bytes for UTF-16, along with what happens for a big-endian encoding and what happens with UTF-8:

```
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub ShowAsHex(bb() As Byte)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", bb.Select(Function(b) Hex(b).PadLeft(2, "0"c))))

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim bb = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("0")
        ShowAsHex(bb)
        bb = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("HELLO")
        ShowAsHex(bb)
        bb = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("HELLO")
        ShowAsHex(bb)
        bb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0")
        ShowAsHex(bb)
        bb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HELLO")
        ShowAsHex(bb)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> 30 00
>   48 00 45 00 4C 00 4C 00 4F 00
>   00 48 00 45 00 4C 00 4C 00 4F
>   30
>   48 45 4C 4C 4F

Notice that there are bytes with a value of zero *within* the longer text ("HELLO"), so they cannot represent EOL/EOF, or even the null-terminator of a C-style string.

So what you interpreted as an EOL/EOF character is actually the other byte of the character in that encoding. EOL on Windows is normally the two bytes 0D 0A, aka CRLF or \r\n.

It appears that you want to use [`Encoding.UTF8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.